# Error Handling for both JsonResult and ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

In `ASP.NET MVC 5`, I'm trying to extend my site's general Error Handling and I'm having trouble to cover `ActionResult` and `JsonResult` in once. I'm aware that `JsonResult` is divered from `ActionResult`, but when I return `ActionResult` I just give MVC a View, and for JsonResult, I handle the result with Javascript.

**So the case**, where the return value for the Action is an ActionResult, and the `Application_Error()` returns a `JsonResult`, the Json with just be printed in the view. What are you supposed to do in that situation? I rather have it to redirect to errorpage or login screen. I don't even know if I'm supossed to craft so javascript that handle the catch of the json to manually redirect or there is some "built-in" MVC mechanisme I should use.

In a simplified example I have the two `Action's`:

```
public ActionResult ShowPackages(PackagesViewModel packagesViewModel)
{
    var model = PackageBalhelper.GetPackageViewModel(packagesViewModel);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDatatableRows(PackagesViewModel packagesViewModel)
{
    var jsonResult = CreateJsonResult(packagesViewModel);
    return jsonResult;
}
```

What I've so far (From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx))

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if (httpContext != null)
    {
        var requestContext = ((MvcHandler)httpContext.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;

        // When the request is ajax the system can automatically handle a mistake with a JSON response. Then overwrites the default response
        if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            string controllerName = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
            IController controller = factory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
            ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, (ControllerBase)controller);

            var jsonResult = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    success = false,
                    serverError = "500"
                },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
            jsonResult.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
            httpContext.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            LogHelper.WriteMessageToLog("In 'Application_Error'. Not an ajax request'.");
            //httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you are calling via javascript needs to be aware of the error and handle it appropriately.  What you do when there is an error is a design decision.  You could just redirect to the error view/page via javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are you supposed to do in that situation? I rather have it to
>   redirect to errorpage or login screen.

You are on the right track. We definitely do not want to return View *(redirect to custom error page)*, if the client expects Json response from server. Otherwise, it will mess up the client's logic.

*This answer might not answer your question directly.* However, if you see yourself returning ***JsonResult*** a lot, you might want to consider using ***Web API Controller*** in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Web API 2.1 supports ***GlobalExceptionHandler*** in which you can customize the Http response that is sent when an unhanded application expcetion occurs.

In my case, I use ***Angular with ASP.NET MVC and Web API***. So, I have to return unhandled exception in Json format for Ajax requests.

### WebApiExceptionHandler.cs

If your application throws custom exception, you can even filter them here, and return appropriate message.

```
public class WebApiExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        var exception = context.Exception;
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            context.Result = new WebApiErrorResult(context.Request,
                (HttpStatusCode) httpException.GetHttpCode(), httpException.Message);
            return;
        }
        /*if (exception is MyCustomException)
        {
            context.Result = new WebApiErrorResult(context.Request, 
                 HttpStatusCode.NotFound, exception.Message);
            return;
        }*/
        context.Result = new WebApiErrorResult(context.Request, 
           HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
          "An error occurred while processing your request.");
    }
}
```

### WebApiErrorResult.cs

```
public class WebApiErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly string _errorMessage;
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _requestMessage;
    private readonly HttpStatusCode _statusCode;

    public WebApiErrorResult(
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage,
        HttpStatusCode statusCode,
        string errorMessage)
    {
        _requestMessage = requestMessage;
        _statusCode = statusCode;
        _errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(_statusCode, _errorMessage));
    }
}
```

### WebApiConfig.cs

Finally, we register our custom exception handler with framework.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new WebApiExceptionHandler());

        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: "if you see yourself returning JsonResult a lot", I would say it's 50/50 if I return a ActionResult or a JsonResult, so is that a lot?

Comment: What do you use Angular for?